# Usage: ‘seek out for’ or ‘seek for’?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, ielts

I have this sentence and wonder if it is grammatically correct:

> Companies have always **sought out for** celebrities to endorse their products.

Should it be just:

> Companies have always **sought for** celebrities to endorse their products.

I'm about to take the IELTS test and these make me nervous.

Comment: **sought out** or **sought for** not both. Or just **sought**.

Comment: I'd recommend omitting the "for" altogether: _Companies have always sought celebrity endorsements_. But I guess that's a different issue. I'd also recommend checking out [ell.se], the community designed to help prospective IELTS-takers calm their nerves.

Answer (score 2):

I would say **sought out** or **sought for** but not both.

Or just [sought](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sought).

> 2 a : to go in search of : look for

According to Merriam-Webster, [sought out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seek%20out) implies searching for *and then successfully finding* (which is a subtlety that was lost on me!):

> to search for and find (someone or something) - His parents **sought out** the best doctors in the field. - White blood cells **seek out** and destroy infections.

Although **sought for** sounds OK to me, there seemed to be few references for it. But the [Oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/seek) says it is British English, so maybe that is why:

> seek for something/somebody (British English) - They **sought** [in vain] **for** somewhere to shelter.

Comment: *Sought in vain for something* sounds perfectly fine to me. On the other hand, *sought for something* sounds horribly wrong. In my head, dropping just *in vain* while leaving *for* shouldn't make any difference; yet, it does. At least in terms of my emotional reaction to it.

Comment: @JasonBassford Interesting. Even for me (BrE) it sounds more slightly natural with "in vain".  Also, the only entry in Merriam-Webster was "sought revenge for" (but that seems a bit different again).